# Wanna get label name but return id,if need change gremlin sentence?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

When using gremlin console to connect gremlin server

```
run gremlin> graph=ConfiguredGraphFactory.open('test');
mgmt=graph.openManagement();mgmt.getVertexLabels()
```

will return:

```
==>person
==>animal
```

but when using the same gremlin sentence in java language to query vertex label
it return:

```
{result{object=v[525] class=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex},
result{object=v[2061] class=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex}}
```

i want to get the label name in java,how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getVertexLabels()` method returns a `VertexLabel`object. That object implements TinkerPop's `Vertex` interface. When you execute that code in Java (presumably via a remote script in JanusGraph Server - i.e. Gremlin Server) the `VertexLabel` is coerced to a `DetachedVertex` - that's just how Gremlin Server treats all `Vertex` instances. I would guess that if you wanted the actual "label" you would simply issue your script to get the label itself:

```
mgmt.getVertexLabels().collect{it.name()}
```

That will coerce the vertex labels to strings and then you'll get what you want.

Comment: i have tried the gremlin sentence you offered,but cannot get the vertexlabel as 'person' or 'animal',

Comment: just get the label 'vertex',it is not what i want to get

Comment: hmm - perhaps use `toString()` rather than `label()` (that's what the console would do)

Comment: my java code is: List<String> result = client.submit("graph=ConfiguredGraphFactory.open('test');
mgmt=graph.openManagement();mgmt.getVertexLabels()").stream().map(r->r.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()); it also returns the DetachedVertex @stephen mallette

Comment: it works! this method  got the actual label of vertex!